# Clean wordpress .css cached from origin files

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

My website is developed in Wordpress and currently in production.

I've noticed `.css` file is cached in `public_html/wp-content/cache/min/1/b1245204d8e0a4ff7cb5d1b2577fb6fa.css` and every time any client request the website the same `.css` and others `.js` files generates several with random names.

Currently I'm on charge optimize WEB Core Vitals and one of the key is Performance, but I have no idea which origin files do I need to edit or modify in order when the cache re-generate those new files apply the origin changes.

It's been challenging to identify which file but not the original one.

I also use Google Dev Tool > Coverage to detect which file is affecting the performance, but it's not a good thing to modify the cached file.

Appreciate any idea or help.

[image]

Comment: Are you using a plugin that optimizes your .css and/or .js files?

Comment: Yes, I think it's a wp rocket.